# Imprimir Objeto JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

tenho esse retorno em JS, e gostaria de imprimir as mensagens assim:

```
Email é Obrigatório!
Limite de Testes é obrigatória!
```

...
e assim sucessivamente. O problema está que no meio do retorno em outro array e não consegui tratar ele, para no cado ai, imprimir assim:

```
Valor é Obrigatório!
Valor é Obrigatório!
```

Preciso imprimir apenas as mensagens.

```
resultado:
email:{_empty: "Email é Obrigatório!"}
limite_teste:{_empty: "Limite de Testes é obrigatória!"}
limite_usuarios:{_empty: "Limite de Usuários é obrigatório!"}
nome:{_empty: "Nome Completo é obrigatório"}
password:{_empty: "Senha é obrigatória!"}
planos:
  Array(2)
   0:_joinData:valor:{_empty: "Valor é Obrigatório!"}
   1:_joinData:valor:{_empty: "Valor é Obrigatório!"}
username:{_empty: "Usuário é obrigatório!"}

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PTXi.png
```

Meu Código:

```
var erro = "";
for(var k in mensagem ){
  for(var i in mensagem[k]){
     erro = erro + mensagem[k][i] + "<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: `_joinData:valor` é uma chave inteira? Tem como postar o json correto?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PTXi.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que basta iterar assim com `for ... in` e para o `planos` tem que usar um `for` iterado com incremento (`i++`), exemplo usando `console.log`:

```js
var data = {
    email:{_empty: "Email é Obrigatório!"},
    limite_teste:{_empty: "Limite de Testes é obrigatória!"},
    limite_usuarios:{_empty: "Limite de Usuários é obrigatório!"},
    nome:{_empty: "Nome Completo é obrigatório"},
    password:{_empty: "Senha é obrigatória!"},
    planos: [
       {
           "_joinData": {
                "valor": {_empty: "Valor é Obrigatório!"}
           }
       }, {
           "_joinData": {
                "valor": {_empty: "Valor é Obrigatório!"}
           }
       }
    ],
    username:{_empty: "Usuário é obrigatório!"}
};

for (var k in data) {
    var item = data[k];

    if (k === "planos") {
        for (var i = 0, j = item.length; i < j; i++) {
           console.log(item[i]._joinData.valor._empty);
        }
    } else {
       console.log(item._empty);
    }
}
```

Salvando tudo na variável erro:

```js
var erro = '', erros = [];

var data = {
    email:{_empty: "Email é Obrigatório!"},
    limite_teste:{_empty: "Limite de Testes é obrigatória!"},
    limite_usuarios:{_empty: "Limite de Usuários é obrigatório!"},
    nome:{_empty: "Nome Completo é obrigatório"},
    password:{_empty: "Senha é obrigatória!"},
    planos: [
       {
           "_joinData": {
                "valor": {_empty: "Valor é Obrigatório!"}
           }
       }, {
           "_joinData": {
                "valor": {_empty: "Valor é Obrigatório!"}
           }
       }
    ],
    username:{_empty: "Usuário é obrigatório!"}
};

for (var k in data) {
    var item = data[k];

    if (k === "planos") {
        for (var i = 0, j = item.length; i < j; i++) {
           erros.push( item[i]._joinData.valor._empty );
        }
    } else {
       erros.push( item._empty );
    }
}

erro = erros.join('<br>');

document.getElementById("erros").innerHTML = erro;
```

```html
<div id="erros"></div>
```

Comment: É isso mesmo brother, funcionou 100%. Obrigado!